# How to plot rectangle in python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have 4 points and want to plot rectangle using it

```
  a=[0,0]
  b=[0,5]
  c=[7,0]
  d=[7,5]
```

is there a way to draw rectangle using matplotlib or seaborn?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0203/:

```
a=[0,0]
b=[0,5]
c=[7,0]
d=[7,5]
width = c[0] - a[0]
height = d[1] - a[1]
lims = (0, 10)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
%matplotlib inline

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax1.add_patch(
    patches.Rectangle((0, 0), width, height))
plt.ylim(lims)
plt.xlim(lims)
```

[image]